# Fill DataTable Column with Data

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to complete an entire Column of an table with an specify data.

I have an Table 1 with the information below:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

Then, I have to add more columns to this table (Could be an "infinite" number of new columns):

| Column1 | Column2 | Added1 | Added2 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |  |

So, this new table has an X number of empty columns. I would like to complete this Columns with an specific value. For example, for the Column Added1 , the value is X; For the Column Added2 another value... (I get this values from another table)

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: It almost sounds like you want query results as if the tables were *joined*?

Comment: Not exactly. The name of this new columns come from an 3° DataTable. But I dont want the existing data of this table. I want a to add other values

Comment: What is a ‘ 3° DataTable’?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the data before you add the new columns

DataTable are collections of DataRow; they don't have "columns of data" they have "rows of data"

```
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("One");
dt.Columns.Add("Two");

for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
  dt.Rows.Add("1","2");

for(int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
  dt.Columns.Add("Added"+x);
```

That gives you a table that looks like your image, with only two columns filled in

You can then run some process to fill data by column if you want:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
  //by column index
  dt.Rows[x][2] = random.Next().ToString();

  //or by col name
  dt.Rows[x]["Added56"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

If you're getting data from other tables or 2d arrays etc a pair of loops will let you address x and y